# Reading from kinesis data streams using nodejs backend application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, iot, amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm currently reading streming iot data from my kinesis data stream (currently running in provisioned mode 1 shard only) , I have written the code for the same and it logs the data currently to the console.

But i want to run the code every few seconds and read the data in batch, say a batch of 15 or 20, or get the data as soon as it is available in the stream,and also want to optimise my code.

Here is my code:

```
const {
  KinesisClient,
  GetRecordsCommand,
  GetShardIteratorCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-kinesis");

const kinesis = new KinesisClient({ region: "ap-south-1" });

const streamName = "my-data-stream";
const shardId = "my-shardId";

const readFromShard = async (shardIterator) => {
  const params = {
    ShardIterator: shardIterator,
    Limit: 50,
  };

  try {
    const command = new GetRecordsCommand(params);
    const response = await kinesis.send(command);
    const records = response.Records;

    if (records.length > 0) {
      records.forEach((record) => {
        let parsedData = Buffer.from(record.Data).toString("utf-8");
        let payload = JSON.parse(parsedData);

        try {
          const timestamp = formatDate(payload.time);
          const updatedData = {
            ...payload,
            time: timestamp,
          };
          console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedData));
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error parsing record data:", error);
        }
      });
    }

    if (!response.NextShardIterator) {
      console.log("No more records available. Terminating.");
      return;
    }

    await readFromShard(response.NextShardIterator);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

const formatDate = (epoch) => {
  const date = new Date(epoch);
  const options = {
    day: "2-digit",
    month: "short",
    year: "numeric",
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit",
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata", // IST timezone
  };

  const timestamp = date.toLocaleString("en-IN", options);
  return timestamp;
};

const startReading = async () => {
  try {
    const params = {
      StreamName: streamName,
      ShardId: shardId,
      ShardIteratorType: "LATEST",
    };

    const command = new GetShardIteratorCommand(params);
    const response = await kinesis.send(command);
    const shardIterator = response.ShardIterator;
    await readFromShard(shardIterator);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
};

startReading();
```

How do I implement the functionality of reading the data from stream as soon as it is available or read data from the stream in batch after certain time frame.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can create a lambda function using the above code with appropriate permissions and then configure the Kinesis Data Stream as the event source for the lambda.  Set Batch Window parameters as per your requirement. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html

Comment: Thank you, but by any chance can I do the same with nodejs?

Comment: There is something called as the KCL which can be used to create library. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-implementation-app-nodejs.html.  To run KCL app you will need multilang daemon which will take care of the processing . It will be better if you explain what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: Sure, what I want to do is read the data from the stream coming from multiple iot devices, in my nodejs app, and write them into a mongodb database table, also the frequency of data is much high I would like to batch the data and write it together to the database rather than writing one by one for each device in the database, Hope I was able to explain what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: The best would be to do through Lambda's which will scale for you and also you dont need manage the infrastructure. Batching and everything will be handled.   Below is similar requirement except its writing to neptune instead of mongo https://aws-samples.github.io/aws-dbs-refarch-graph/src/writing-from-amazon-kinesis-data-streams/